# Flash async calls with mouse click permissions?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

The current workflow is as follows:

```
user clicks a button
  sends a Loader to see if the user has permission
  if the user has permission
    uploads a file
```

Unfortunately, this gives:

```
SecurityError: Error #2176: Certain actions, such as those that display a pop-up window, may only be invoked upon user interaction, for example by a mouse click or button press.
```

It appears that as a security feature, Flash 10 disallows certain functions (such as uploading a file) unless it is preceded by a mouse click or button press.  However, since I am first loading the request for permission, it no longer see the MouseEvent event (presumably in the stack) and thus throws a SecurityError.

Any solutions for getting around it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Still on Flash 9 here, but can you not try to upload in the first place, without having that loader to check, and if that fails, prompt the user ?

as Cory mentions

what about try,catch ?

```
try{
//upload file
}catch(e:SecurityError){
//prompt user, etc.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make your workflow

```
user clicks a button
    uploads a file

listen for file upload security issue
    report issue
```

Comment: Makes sense.  Unfortunately, the API doesn't report any issue - if you don't have permission for it, it will not fail, just does a subset of what it should do..

Comment: Not knowing your API, all I can say is that you have to re-engineer it. Flash 10 added this unfortunate "feature" and it's taken a lot of possibilities away from everybody.